# Unable to read a zip file from MSI package

Tags: .net, asp.net-core, advanced-installer

I am using Advanced installer version 18.6.1. I've created a MSI package with .NET Core API app. I want to read a zip file in my application from APPDIR directory added from "Files and Folders". The exception from my logs;

*An unhandled exception of type 'System.UnauthorizedAccessException'
occurred in System.IO.Compression.FileSystem.dll
Additional information: Access to the path 'C:\My_App_Dir_Includes_Zip\My_Zip_File.zip' is denied.*

**Note:** I added IIS_USER and SYSTEM user roles while packaging the MSI file which are assigned to my "My_App_Dir_Includes_Zip" folder.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 1):

This may happens if you need to impersonate installing user. From the file download operation dialog you need to enable the "Impersonate installing user" option:
[image]

This way, the file download operation is done as the user installing the application, not under the Local System account.

If using Program Files as install location, you may need admin privileges when extracting the archive. Or, you can assign *Everyone* write permissions in that location through the [Permissions](https://www.advancedinstaller.com/user-guide/permissions.html) tab.

Note that Advanced Installer offers also predefined funcionality to [Extract Archive](https://www.advancedinstaller.com/user-guide/extract-archive-dialog.html).

Comment: thanks for the answer but it didn't work. I want to give some more details. In Advanced Installer "Files and Folders" section (which is responsible for the folder/file permissions, I think) has my .Net Core API application on IIS WWW Root section. I have 3 user roles added in my IIS app folder: [GRP_ADMINISTRATORS], [GRP_IIS_USERS] and [GRP_SYSTEM]. Any other config should be made inside the Advanced Installer GUI?

Comment: It's not very clear for me the settings that you have on your project. Can you please send the .AIP(project file) to "support@advancedinstaller.com" so that we can further investigate this? Also add a link to this conversation on StackOverflow so that we can identify you easier. Disclaimer: I'm part of the support team of Advanced Installer.